# Orbeon Forms - Uploading attachments and retrieving

Tags: web-services, pdf, orbeon

I have a requirement to attach a PDF file with a form created by using Orbeon Form builder. Is there an inbuilt form builder control which I can use for this and please help me to retrieve the attached PDF file when the Orbeon form is submitted.

Comment: Hi, I found out that there is a control called file attachment which allows to upload a file. Suppose I am submitting the form using a button click to a web service. Could I please know how to retrieve the attached PDF of the form generated from the web service? Or is there an easy other option? Thank you

Comment: Yes, using the File Attachment control is the way to go. When users submit the data, what happens to the data in your setup? Are you saving it to a database using the built-in persistence? And when do you need the PDF? Is this for a batch process or do you need it as soon as it is submitted?

Comment: Thank you, no I'm not saving in to database. But instead I'm sending the form as a PDF to a web service, in this web service now I want to extract the attached PDF too (in addition to the form PDF)Could you please help me.

Comment: Hi, @avernet could you please help me to figure out, how to send form attachments to a web-service? Thank you

Comment: This is the response I got `/fr/service/persistence/crud/MonashHealth/COIPROCUREMENT/data/227e8caa7533ea6d3df7b97721e017e9b7881c83/1528770e3b9c5daaf46619694010ab50ccac8ebd.bin`                                Could you please help me to save the file in a folder in my local disk using this response. Thank you.

Comment: So I imagine that in your `properties-local.xml`, you have a process that uses the [`send()` action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#send) to POST the PDF to a service; is that correct? If you want the attachments, you need to do a `send(content = "xml")`, and the XML will contain a URL that your code can call back to retrieve the PDF attachment (or, in general, any attachment).

Comment: In future, we're looking into [supporting multipart for attachments](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/788), so you can avoid doing that callback.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @avernet . Yes I have a process that uses the send() action and now I can retrieve the the URL from the `xml`. Could you please let me know how the URL is formed. Do I need to add any other parameters or details before `/fr/service/persistence/crud/MonashHealth/COIPROCUREMENT/dat‌​a/227e8caa7533ea6d3d‌​f7b97721e017e9b7881c‌​83/1528770e3b9c5daaf‌​46619694010ab50ccac8‌​ebd.bin` part? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @avernet, I tried the following URL to get my attachment `http://192.168.25.49:8080/fr/service/persistence/crud/MonashHealth/COIPROCUREMENT/dat‌​‌​a/227e8caa7533ea6d‌​3d‌​f7b97721e017e9b7‌​881c‌​83/1528770e3b9‌​c5daaf‌​46619694010a‌​b50ccac8‌​ebd.bin`. 192.168.25.49 is the IP on which Orbeon is running and 8080 is the port. But I do not get the file by using the above mentioned URL. Could you please help me to get the correct format of the URL? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @avernet, also may I please know if there is any property to be set/added to the `properties-local.xml` in order to obtain this function? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @avernet, I tried to give the URL as follows `http://192.168.25.49:8080/prbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/Monash‌​Health/COIPROCUREMEN‌​T/dat‌​‌​a/227e8caa7‌​533ea6d‌​3d‌​f7b9772‌​1e017e9b7‌​881c‌​83/‌​1528770e3b9‌​c5daaf‌‌​​46619694010a‌​b50cc‌​ac8‌​ebd.bin` but it gives a 403 error in the browser. When I tried to get the attachment file using the same URL in my rest service, I again got the same error. Please find my code below

Comment: `public static void downloadAttachmentbyURL(String fileAttach_Receipt) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String attachUrl = "http://"+APP_IP+":"+APP_PORT+"/orbeon"+fileAttach_Receipt;
        URL url = new URL(attachUrl);
        System.out.println("URL : "+url);
        String fileName = "name";
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, new File(PDF_SAVE_PATH + "\\"+fileName.concat(".bin")));  
}` please help me to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: After your service receives the URL, can you try opening that URL you received in your browser, the same browser (session) used to submit the form? Are you able to retrieve the file this way?

Comment: Hi @avernet, I did try to load the URL on the same browser but I get an error saying can not load page, and when I check network headers form developer tools in the browser it says 403 error. Could you please help me to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: OK, sorry for the confusion: it's not a matter of `JSESSIONID`, but instead, since you're trying to access an Orbeon Forms "service", you need to allow access to that service from outside Orbeon Forms. First, check that you're able to retrieve the attachment after setting the 2 properties in this [Backward compatibility](https://doc.orbeon.com/xml-platform/controller/authorization-of-pages-and-services.html#backward-compatibility).

Comment: If that works, you won't want to leave those properties as-is, as it would allow anyone to access the persistence API, while you only want your own code to be able to do that. So go through the rest of the page linked in my previous comment to see how to do that.

Comment: Thank you! @avernet

Comment: Great @n.path, I'm glad you managed to make this work. And I think things will get simpler once we add [support for multi-part attachments](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/788).

Comment: I also posted an answer with a summary of what we talked about in the comments so far.

Comment: @avernet could you please explain how support for multi-part attachments work? Does this need to be added in the properties-local-prod.xml file to get it to be working? If so what is the syntax? And how do I retrieve in the send() process? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon users submitting the form, Orbeon Forms can run a [process](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/) you define. This process can use the [`send()` action](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#send) to have the data entered by users sent through an HTTP POST to a service you provide.

If files were attached to the form, the data your service receives will contain one or multiple URLs pointing back to Orbeon Forms. Your service can then use those URLs to retrieve the attachments. So your service can make those calls back to Orbeon Forms and retrieve the files, it will be need to be [authorized to do so](https://doc.orbeon.com/xml-platform/controller/authorization-of-pages-and-services.html).

Comment: Thank you so much @avernet !.

Comment: could you please explain how support for multi-part attachments work? Does this need to be added in the properties-local-prod.xml file to get it to be working? If so what is the syntax? And how do I retrieve in the send() process? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: When using `send()`, files attached to the form data are not sent to the URL you provide. Instead, the XML document sent to the service contains URLs pointing to Orbeon Forms, and your service can use those URLs to retrieve the files. In some cases, it would indeed be more convenient to have the files sent in a multipart attachment, but this isn't supported right now, and is tracked by [request for enhancement 788](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/788). Does this help?

Comment: thank you for the reply. I could get the URL of the XML document and when I put it on the browser URL I get a binary file downloaded. Currently developing the web service. Can I please know if we could also get the file type/extension of those attachments?

Comment: The data (XML document) has attributes with this information on the element corresponding to the file, namely the `filename="…"` and `mediatype="…"`. You'll let me know if this works for you.

Comment: yes this worked, I could now download the same attachment from its original form thanks a lot.