# Orbeon Forms - Multiple Attachments

Tags: attachment, orbeon

Can I please know if multiple attachments could be added to a form created in Orbeon forms through a single form control (single File Attachment control) with out using multiple File Attachment controls? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is currently not possible. There is [an RFE](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3079) to enhance this.

Comment: The RFE says that as a work around to create a repeated grid containing a file attachment control. When I do this and get the XML file I do not receive a URL for each attachment as mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546185/orbeon-forms-uploading-attachments-and-retrieving) . Instead I receive the file path from which the attachments were added. Ex: `file:/C:/Program%20Files/apache-tomcat-8.0.48/temp/xforms_upload_3849731886854450683.tmp?filename=20171120_102510.jpg&amp;mediatype=image%2Fjpeg&amp;size=7807462&amp;mac=2fba7d60e045f693b28401392de6fef26136f69b`. Please help.

Comment: @n.path I suspect you're seeing this because the data hasn't been saved yet. In the process that runs the `send()` that gets the data to where you'll be using it, make sure you run  [`save`](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/actions-form-runner.html#save) first.

Comment: @avernet I tried saving using a seperate button too. And my `send()` button has a `save-final` too. `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.ELOForms.*" value="http://192.168.25.42:8081/OrbeonRest/rest/xml"/> <property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.ELOForms.*" value='require-valid then save-final then send("oxf.fr.detail.send.success", content="xml", replace="none")'/>  `                                But yet in my XML file I get the full file path of those attachments.

Comment: @n.path This doesn't sound right: if you're doing a `save-final` before the `send`, then the URL shouldn't point to the local file system anymore (e.g. `file:/C:/…` as mentioned in your earlier message). Is this really what you are seeing?